# Model agnostic way to normalize output tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

If I perform classification loading model files in Tensorflow, the output tensor values have ranges that are very different according the model used.

Getting the maximum and minimum values from output tensor itself to normalize would give inconsistent results because in this way the maximum and minimum used for normalization would be dependent on the current classified object results rather than the model range values. So, I would get values in range 0, 1 that are not comparable from a classification to another.

Is there a way to determine what are the possible maximum and minimum values according model so that values can be consistently normalized in [0, 1] range?